# Android scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, footer

While I am doing a screen i am getting a problem.
The code of the screen is below

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="40dp"
>     android:padding="5dp"
>     android:background="@android:color/black"
>     android:id="@+id/header"
>     android:gravity="center">
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Header"
>         android:id="@+id/textView"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>         android:textSize="20dp"
>         android:textStyle="bold"/>
> </RelativeLayout>
>
> <ScrollView
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/scrollView"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/header"
>     >
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:padding="20dp"
>         android:id="@+id/linear"
>         android:background="@android:color/white"
>
>         >
>
>         <View
>             android:layout_width="20dp"
>             android:layout_height="20dp"
>             android:id="@+id/space"/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:id="@+id/ft_lab_title"
>             android:text="Welcome"
>             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>             android:textSize="30dp"
>             android:layout_gravity="center"/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="One"
>             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>             android:id="@+id/ft_lab_fromAcc"/>
>
>         <View
>             android:layout_width="20dp"
>             android:layout_height="20dp"
>             android:id="@+id/space"/>
>
>         <EditText
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:id="@+id/a"
>             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>             android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="Two"
>             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>             android:id="@+id/ft_lab_toAcc"/>
>
>         <View
>             android:layout_width="20dp"
>             android:layout_height="20dp"
>             android:id="@+id/space"/>
>
>         <EditText
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:id="@+id/b"
>             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>             android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="Three"
>             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>             android:id="@+id/ft_lab_amt"/>
>
>         <EditText
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:id="@+id/c"
>             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>             android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
>
>         <View
>             android:layout_width="20dp"
>             android:layout_height="20dp"
>             android:id="@+id/space"/>
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="OK"
>             android:id="@+id/ft_bt_submit"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
> </ScrollView>
>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="40dp"
>     android:id="@+id/footer"
>     android:background="@android:color/black"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:gravity="center">
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Footer"
>         android:id="@+id/textView1"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>         android:textSize="20dp"
>         android:textStyle="bold"/>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

the screen is

[image]

when i click on the edit text then the footer is coming on the top of the keyboard

its image is

[image]

if i remove the scroll view it is getting correctly
and its image is

[image]

I am not able to find out the real problem.
Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to add

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

to your manifest?

something like:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity">

 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

</activity>
```